# Android JAVA not getting exact latitude and longitude

Tags: java, android, cordova, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I am using below code to get latitude and longitude of the current location

```
address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
if (address==null) {
    return null;
}
Address location=address.get(0);
location.getLatitude();
location.getLongitude();

p1 = new GeoPoint((double) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), (double) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

return p1;
```

The problem is :

1. it is not giving exact location, instead it is providing 50 mts apart.
2. upon starting GPS and wi-fi this code returns "null".

I want some technique where i can ask user to keep marker at exact location and then i can take location out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose Google Place Picker if you want to get selected location from user:
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker

Comment: Thanks, Okset but can i use this with cordova applications?

Comment: Im not sure, but i just googled it https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-place-picker